# Problem with (Graphics g, Graphics2D) on Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, graphics2d

I cant keep the past line i draw with "g2d.drawLine(w, x, y, z);",
I call "repaint()" to update the Jpanel and it just draws a new Line, I need to keep the past Lines i have draw.

What it should do: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gw1F.jpg)

What id do:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kkkq.jpg)

Comment: You have to save the line endpoints in an application model made up of plain old Java classes.  Every time you want to repaint the JPanel, you have to repaint the entire JPanel.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ArrayList of Point objects, every time you do whatever calculation you're doing, just save the end point to it. Every time the panel repaints, just draw lines between all of the points in your ArrayList, in the same order they were added.